# SMTP / POP3 / IMAP Mail Server for Windows

Tags: .net, sql-server, smtp

I'm looking for a relatively inexpensive (or free) POP3 mail server for Windows Server that will scale well.  Compatible with SQL Server would be fantastic.  It would also be great if it had a .net class library for performing simple functions like creating/deleting new accounts, adding aliases, etc.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question; this is better served in experts exchange.  But since you asked nicely, something like sendmail will work.

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&fkt=684&fsdt=&q=pop3+server+windows&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g3

Comment: Suroot - Thanks for the comment.  Do you consider Expert Exchange worth the money?

Answer (score 5):

Google Search turned this up (It's freeware):

http://www.hmailserver.com/

Also see  this other topic:

[SMTP and IMAP server library for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249047/smtp-and-imap-server-library-for-net)

Comment: Looking it over, it supports everything you wanted and more.  Even has support for Active-Directory built-in.

Comment: I ran into this one in a thread I saw earlier today.  Wonder if there is anything else that fits the bill that I could compare this one to?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not really sure.  I just learned everything I know about it in the past 20 minutes.  Personally, I've never had to setup a mail server on Windows.  I've always used linux servers.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 1):

Also, a free 'combo' pack.  Use VMWare Server, which is free, with Ubuntu, which is free and Zimbra network edition, also free.  Zimbra will include POP3, IMAP, calendaring, task lists, and a full web interface if you need it.

A fantastic little package

[www.vmware.com](http://www.vmware.com)
[www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com)
[www.zimbra.com](http://www.zimbra.com)

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend MailEnable. www.mailenable.com