# How to authenticate an incoming email transmission in SMTP server?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, smtp-auth

I'm using the code from [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/286952/create-a-simple-smtp-server-in-csharp) to write my own SMTP server.

So far I have this code (just a snippet from the project I linked to above):

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, nListeningPort);
listener.Start();

TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

//How do I authenticate incoming SMTP connection?
//In other words, how do I check user name and password?

//Begin reading stream
System.IO.StreamReader reader;
System.IO.StreamWriter writer;

reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream);
writer.NewLine = "\r\n";
writer.AutoFlush = true;

for (string line = reader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = reader.ReadLine())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Read line {0}", line);

    switch (line)
    {
        case "DATA":
            writer.WriteLine("354 Start input, end data with <CRLF>.<CRLF>");
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

            //And so on...

            writer.WriteLine("250 OK");
            client.Close();
            break;

        //Other cases...
    }
}
```

It works fine, but it accepts any SMTP connection.

My question is how do I authenticate it, or check for correct use name and password?

**EDIT:** I just realized that it is important to add the following. I need to code this SMTP server for our intranet to service outbound emails from one particular application (that I cannot control source code for.)

The application evidently uses [`Redemption.SafeMailItem`](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeMailItem.htm) object as the SMTP client to send out emails. Here's pseudo code that I got from disassembling it:

```
//Code below was extracted using dotPeek

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = Interaction.CreateObject("Outlook.Application", "");
SafeMailItem safeMailItem = Interaction.CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem", "");

MailItem mailItem = application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
safeMailItem.Item = mailItem;

safeMailItem.Recipients.Add(strRecipient);
safeMailItem.Body = sBody;

safeMailItem.Attachments.Add((object) strPath, (object) Missing.Value, (object) Missing.Value, (object) Missing.Value);

NewLateBinding.LateSet((object) safeMailItem, (Type) null, "Subject", new object[1]
{
     (object) sSubject
}, (string[]) null, (Type[]) null);

safeMailItem.Send();
application.GetNamespace("MAPI").SyncObjects[(object) 1].Start();
```

Comment: SMTP supports different mechanisms for authentication (e.g. `PLAIN`) and different transport protocols. What mechanisms and protocols do you want to support? Do you really want to write an SMTP server from scratch? Does the code that you referenced maybe already support any of your requirements? Maybe you want to use an existing working library that implements an SMTP server. For the latter you find plenty of examples such as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249047/smtp-and-imap-server-library-for-net

Comment: @RonaldRink'd-fens' Yeah, I need to write it. It's not a production server. I need it for our own intranet. Do you have any more info on those `different mechanisms for authentication` you mentioned?

Comment: @RonaldRink'd-fens': Add some details in my original post. Does it clear it up?

Comment: sorry for being unclear about `different mechanisms for authentication`. You can have a look at various RFCs such as [Using TLS with IMAP, POP3 and ACAP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2595). From there you can find other linked RFCs that supersede RFC2595 and provide additional details. An example for `AUTH PLAIN` can be found [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4954#section-4.1).
Having a look at your updated code, it seems that the client is using `MAPI` (via COM) and not `SMTP` at all. Is this correct?